# OpenCV Dense SIFT block size

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, feature-extraction, feature-detection, sift

I know from other posts that I can extract dense features from image with following code(python):

```
dense=cv2.FeatureDetector_create("Dense")
kp=dense.detect(imgGray)
kp,des=sift.compute(imgGray,kp)
```

Say, I'd like to have the block size of SIFT descriptor set to 20X20(instead of 16X16 default), with 4X4 bins(as default), each bin size 5X5, to compute the gradient statistics, is there a way to do so? (python or c++)

**Update:**

As suggested by Rick M., I read the document, but still cannot figure out the way the dense detector is constructed. Especially the role of 'scale'. In the document, it wrote:

```
 class DenseFeatureDetector : public FeatureDetector
{
public:
        DenseFeatureDetector( float initFeatureScale=1.f, int featureScaleLevels=1,
                      float featureScaleMul=0.1f,
                      int initXyStep=6, int initImgBound=0,
                      bool varyXyStepWithScale=true,
                      bool varyImgBoundWithScale=false );
protected:
...
};
```

with explaination as follows:

```
The detector generates several levels (in the amount of 
featureScaleLevels) of features. Features of each level are located in the
nodes of a regular grid over the image (excluding the image boundary of 
given size). The level parameters (a feature scale, a node size, a size of 
boundary) are multiplied by featureScaleMul with level index growing
depending on input flags, viz.:

 -Feature scale is multiplied always.
 -The grid node size is multiplied if varyXyStepWithScale is true.
 -Size of image boundary is multiplied if varyImgBoundWithScale is true.
```

I suppose what I want to do is to set grid node size as 20, so I think I should set **featureScaleMul** = 20.0f/16. Is that right?

The current method I use is use the default dense detector and set the _size of returned key points to 20 one by one, and I'm not sure that's what I want.

Comment: Can't you initialize the constructor with the desired parameters instead? Something like given [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#featuredetector-create). Only for C++ but I am sure you can do the same in python.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't used dense SIFT so I don't know much about that. You should read the implementation, then hopefully you can get what they mean by the constructor parameters.